# `print_r($mysqli,1)` changes `$mysqli->affected_rows `

Tags: php, mysqli

I was using user-assert functions like :

```
debug_assert (
    gettype($ob)=='object', 
    "Not an object <pre>"
        .print_r($ob,1).'</pre>' 
    ) or exit;
```

but i found out that print_r changes results of $mysqli->affected_rows 's when called on $mysqli : it resets affected_rows from previous 'n' to -1.

Test code :

```
$q= "INSERT INTO t_envois SET id_contact=243";

if (!$mysqli) die ("missing mysqli");
$ok = $mysqli->query($q);
if (!$ok) die ("bad query $q : ".$mysqli->errno.") ".$mysqli->error);

function get_affected_rows() {
    global $mysqli;
    return $mysqli->affected_rows;
}

echo "1) ".($mysqli->affected_rows)."<br>"; // 1
echo "2) ".($mysqli->affected_rows)."<br>"; // 1
echo "3) ".get_affected_rows()."<br>";    // 1 try other function
echo "4) ".get_affected_rows()."<br>";    // 1 (no issue)
echo "5) ".(print_r($mysqli,1))."<br>";    // affected_rows shown as 1
echo "6) ".($mysqli->affected_rows)."<br>"; // -1 CHANGED !!
echo "7) ".get_affected_rows()."<br>";    // -1 etc
```

How can the result change from 1 to -1 when print_r is called ? Are there other non-sql functions that change $mysqli fields ? Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: What does `see 1 1st call` mean?

Comment: "see 1 1st call" meant that you can see in print_r output that affected_rows is 1. In the example there is only one call of print_r so i've edited that comment to reflect this.

Comment: Can confirm this on PHP 7.2.10 on linux with `var_dump()` as well. Might be related to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67348.

Comment: Yes @Progman it looks like it. So this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Progman stated it's related to a long standing php bug : http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67348

stat, print_r, var_dump and possibly other function that call 'stat' do reset affected_rows to -1.

It's now fixed in PHP>7.4 that has no `stat` property anymore, but a `stat()` method

In my case the workaround for php<=7.3 has been to rewrite a fixed print_r-like function :

```
function print_it($thing) {
    if ((gettype ($thing) == 'object') 
        and (get_class($thing) == 'mysqli'))
        echo "...\naffected_rows => ".$thing->affected_rows."...";
    else 
        print_r($thing);
}
```